# unknown signal error in single line script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, systemd

I was working on a simple bash script when I kept on getting this weird error message.

`[1] # unknown signal ./my_script`

Where signal `#` changes after each failure. What is weird is that I only get this error message around one third of the time (the other times the script will run fine). I managed to narrow down and find the command that was the culprit, which is below. The behavior is the same regardless of the name or state of the service.

```
#!/bin/bash

systemctl --user is-active waybar_redshift.service
```

Running this command in the terminal works fine. So what in the world is going on here!

- zsh error output:

  ```
  11663 unknown signal  /path/to/my/script
  ```
- bash error output:

  ```
  Real-time signal 8
  ```

edit: after copying the script to another file, the new script works perfectly, even though it is a carbon copy of the other including permissions and ownership

Comment: What is `<./my_script>`?

Comment: just the path to my script, will remove brackets it is confusing

Comment: Maybe try putting the absolute path, if you haven't tried already.

Comment: that is the error message, like i said it will run fine 1/3 of the time without that error

Comment: The shebang should probably be `#!/bin/sh`, but really the question is why are you running the service in that way (inside a bash script)?

Comment: i have tried `#!/bin/sh` no difference. i am not running any service, i am simply checking if a service is active. and i am running it by typing the absolute path into the terminal. oddly enough i tried using `bash /absolute/path/to/script` and the error is no longer. i am still really curious as to why i am getting this behavior though

Comment: I think `--user` might be to blame then, perhaps try it without.

Comment: same behavior for any variation, eg starting or stopping, etc... including that

Comment: Then it's got to be something in the service itself causing it. Post the output of `systemctl cat waybar_redshift.service`.

Comment: i have tried different services, ie not custom ones and the exact same issue

Comment: I would suggest then to put a couple of lines before the `is-active` to see what it outputs `systemctl status ...`, `systemctl is-enabled ...`, and `systemctl is-failed`. ( all with `waybar_redshift.service`). See what it comes back with.

Comment: ok things just got really really weird. i literally copied and pasted the script into a new file (exact permissions and ownership and in same folder) and it runs fine without the error!!!! i even did a binary diff and there is ZERO difference between the files so i am just more confused then ever.

Comment: Interesting. It did seem like something was amiss for sure not a common problem unless something is crashing, etc.